# How to wait for the combination of a CSS and an XPath selector in Python WebDriver?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I'd like to keep my selectors simple when possible, and only use XPath where absolutely necessary. So rather than waiting for an XPath like `//*[@class='files']/tbody/tr[1]/th[text()='filename']` I'd rather want to wait for the *combination* of the simple CSS selector `.files tbody tr:first-child` and the simple XPath `th[text()='filename']`.

`presence_of_element_located` only takes a single locator, so `presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.files tbody tr:first-child'), (By.XPATH, 'th[text()='filename']'))` is out.

I can't chain these functions either, so `presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.files tbody tr:first-child')).presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, 'th[text()='filename']'))` won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your custom method:

```
def find_element_by_combo(self, ancestor_locator, descendant_locator, timeout=10, index=0):
    # Getting list of ancestors
    try:
        ancestors =  wait(self, timeout).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(ancestor_locator))
    except:
        return None
    # Getting descendant
    for ancestor in ancestors:
        if ancestor.find_elements(*descendant_locator):
            return ancestor.find_elements(*descendant_locator)[index]
```

and use it as below

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome

Chrome.find_element_by_combo = find_element_by_combo

driver = Chrome()
driver.get(URL)
driver.find_element_by_combo(('css', '.files tbody tr:first-child'), ('xpath', './th[text()="filename"]'))
```

But IMHO it's better just to use XPath for complicated situations